# How do I extracting the multidimensional array value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I get the value of the associative arrays for the year and quarter in a loop in php? I want to extract the numbers like 2021 4, the other value doesn't matter.

```
    $this->financials[2021][4] = 5;
    $this->financials[2022][1] = 7;
    $this->financials[2022][2] = 9;
    $this->financials[2022][3] = 11;
```

I attempted this method, but it didn't work, but hopefully gives you a better idea of what I am trying to achieve. I was hoping for the result e.g. 20214

```
    foreach($this->financials as $f[$y][$q]) {
        echo $y.$q;
    }
```

Comment: You have been a member of Stack Overflow for 9.5 years.  It is fair for the community to assume that you to understand how the site works and how to search for pre-existing questions and answers.  Please search/research more before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

$q in your foreach loop is an associative array so you have to break it down with another loop.

```
foreach ($this->financials as $year => $quarterArray) {
    foreach ($quarterArray as $quarter => $value) {
        echo $year.$quarter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help Stack Overflow to consolidate and reduce its redundant content by flagging/voting to close duplicate questions instead of answering them.